# как получить практику по джава

Tags: java

Изучаю java 2 месяца... Проблема в том что теория то идет по немногу, но не могу ничего сам написать. Вот такая задача на парсинг:

> В тексте слова заданной длины заменить указанной подстрокой, длина
>   которой может не совпадать с длиной слова.

Вопрос: Каким именно способом надо это писать? (либо на стрингах, либо на паттернах или на снер). И есть ли какой-то практику? Книга или видео, где бы это все было по типах так, как в математике (сам учитель математики).

Comment: Ну надо потихоньку. Сперва HelloWorld, затем какую-нибудь сумму элементов массива, затем ещё чего-нибудь посложнее. И так далее.

Comment: По какой книге Вы изучаете java?

Comment: Разние!!  Готовимся на сдачу сертификата...  Это и Шылдт, Сиерра, Еккель, Мухортов, Вязовик и другие

Comment: @BogdanTanchak, У Шилдта же есть упражнения, насколько я помню.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала пройди бесплатные практические туториалы по java. Например на [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java). Задания довольно интересные, после того как наберешь 100% курса переходи на [codewars](http://codewars.com).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте пройти курсы на javarush. Там первые 10 лекций бесплатные. Если увидите свой прогресс, то можете купить остальные, если не понравится, то ищите задачки в интернете и просто их решайте. Но на javarush очень много практических задач. Там можно хорошо поднять свой навык решения задач.